# how to spin linux server in IBM bluemix?

Tags: virtual-machine, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

I want to spin Linux server (VM) in IBM bluemix. But I am not able to find single reference document to do this. Can someone please help me out on this?

Comment: Start here https://www.ibm.com/cloud-computing/bluemix/virtual-servers

Comment: Thanks for the link. I already went though it. Well actually I am looking for proper documentation on these things. Do you know if any?

Comment: Have you looked at the info on the Bluemix Infrastructure/SoftLayer site? Try here: http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/introduction-virtual-servers-0